# How to close a .NET ODBC connection?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using ODBC to connect to a Sybase databse. The problem is the connection doesn't close even after it's is scope complete, and I see around 200 connection open in the database when I run `sp_who`. I tried enabling the connection pool, but that doesn't help either.

```
    using(var connection = GetOdbcConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, connection))
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                long textLen = reader.GetChars(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

The connection string which I use is `value="Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};app=xxx;server=xxxx;port=xxxx; db=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxxx;textsize=2097152"`.

**Update:**

```
public static OdbcConnection GetOdbcConnection() {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    return new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Comment: What does `GetOdbcConnection` do?

Comment: public static OdbcConnection GetOdbcConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
               return new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `connection.Close()`?

```
 using(var connection = GetOdbcConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, connection))
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                long textLen = reader.GetChars(0, 0, null, 0, 0);

            }
            reader.Close();
        }            
        // Close the connection
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Normally this shouldn't be an issue, because `Close` and `Dispose` are synonymous in the `OdbcConnection`-Object. It should be automatically called with the end of the scope of `using`.

Comment: Then maybe there are other methods that open connections but don't use a using statement and forget to call the .Close() explicitly? As Bobby said, the using should close the connection.

Comment: *Close()* is called at the end of the *using* block - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a try.. catch and finally...

Under Finally explicitly check if the connection.state is not closed.. close it..

Comment: the using statement is converted by the compiler to exactly the same IL as a try / finally statement.

Answer (score 0):

Connection to database would be closed automatically when the `using` block ends. You don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: nope that doesnt help, I still can see connection active when I run sp_who after that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the GetOdbcConnection function is the culprit. Try this modified version of the function.

```
private static OdbcConnection _Connection;
public static OdbcConnection GetOdbcConnection() { 
    string connectionString = 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString(); 
    _Connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    return _Connection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ado.net keeps connections opened to reuse than, it´s called connection pool.
I think for odbc connections, pooling are configured under odbc settings in windows.
for other kinds of connection like SqlConenction, you can configure pooling feature in connection string.

hope it helps.